# MySQL long_query_time Seems to be Ignored

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

I added the following to MySQL config file...

```
slow_query_log=1
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
long_query_time=1
slow_query_log_file='slow_queries.log'
```

So why would the log file contain entries like this that are less than 1 sec...

> Query_time: 0.009779  Lock_time: 0.000054  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 6075

I have read this: [The minimum and default values of long_query_time are 0 and 10, respectively. The value can be specified to a resolution of microseconds. For logging to a file, times are written including the microseconds part. For logging to tables, only integer times are written; the microseconds part is ignored.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)

Does that mean I need to specify a certain number of zeros after the 1?

Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

version 10.0.23-MariaDB-wsrep-log

Thanks!

Comment: `I added the following to Apache config file...` <-- that's your problem.  Apache is not MySQL/MariaDB.  You need to add it to that config file.  If that was just a typo.. did you restart?  The server doesn't reread the config file at all once it's started.

Comment: That was a typo I just recognized. Fixed.  Yes, it was restarted.  There was never a log, those 4 lines were never present, I added them, restarted, and it created the file and started logging.

Comment: I would log into MySQL / MariaDB and run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';` and see what the server itself thinks the settings are while it's running.

Comment: @yoonix Good idea, thanks, I changed it to `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%long%';` and it did show `1.000000` so I guess I have it set correctly.  It appears to be because of the `log_queries_not_using_indexes` setting, I should have researched more, thanks tho: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29582/enabling-log-queries-not-using-indexes-disables-long-query-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log_queries_not_using_indexes=1` logs *all* queries that do not use indexes, regardless of how fast they are, because they are performance killers in waiting.

With `Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 6075` it's an entirely safe bet that this query was logged for that reason.

Comment: Yep, thank you, I should have caught that.  For future readers here are some more details on this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29582/enabling-log-queries-not-using-indexes-disables-long-query-time